# Insert New Records / Ignore Existing Records / List Missing Records - SSIS

Tags: ssis, lookup

I am hoping I might get some advice here on how to handle this situation in a SSIS package I am developing.

First a little background. We host events that are assigned a unique Drive ID.  And each event may have multiple shifts that are assigned unique Shift IDs.

From an Oracle source database, I am extracting ShiftIDs plus PersonIDs (and First and Last Name). And I would like to update a specific table in an existing SQL Server database.

I see three things that can happen when performing the operation:

1. New records are inserted into the table
2. Existing records that have not changed are ignored
3. Shift IDs that do not exist are not inserted (possibly sent to another table for auditing/record keeping).

I know how to handle scenario 1, but how best should I handle scenarios 2 & 3?

Answer (score 0):

Strickly within SSIS the answer would be the Slowly Changing Dimension transformation.  But this was poorly built when it first came out in 2005 and has not been maintained or improved since, e.g. there is (silently) no support for datetime2 datatype.  Many blog posts complain about it's slow performance (row-by-row execution), but I've found it does OK with the right indexing strategy.  Anyway I cant recommend it.

I would dump the Data Flow output into a Staging table (on the target SQL Server), then use a SQL MERGE command to handle all 3 scenarios.  After writing a ton of code, you will have a reliable, scalable solution.